# bootstrap modal: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'backdrop') modal.js:158

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am new to bootstrap. I am trying to write a basic CRUD page with user system using PHP, MySQL and Bootstrap. The CRUD page has a button to add new product, and a table to display all the product details created by this user.

The bug I met is related to "add new product" button. Once I click it, the modal is supposed to pop up, and ask for details to enter. I found that if a user already has products stored in the database, the modal will work as expected. However, if a user hasn't posted any product yet, click the button will not open the modal but cause this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'backdrop') modal.js:158
    at Ni._initializeBackDrop (modal.js:158:39)
    at new Ni (modal.js:69:27)
    at Ni.getOrCreateInstance (base-component.js:65:41)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (modal.js:363:22)
    at HTMLDocument.n (event-handler.js:118:19)
```

I searched and tried several solutions, but none of them work me out. For example, include bootstrap's js before the end of , remove condition clause if modal is within that, downgrade bootstrap version, ... I really appreciate it if someone can help or give some hint about possible causes or how to find the cause.

When I looking into trace error (modal.js):

```
  // Private
  _initializeBackDrop() {
    return new Backdrop({
      isVisible: Boolean(this._config.backdrop), // 'static' option will be translated to true, and booleans will keep their value,
      isAnimated: this._isAnimated()
    })
  }
```

My code to trigger modal:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#addModal">
    Add a new product
</button>
```

modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addModal" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1"
     aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel">Add a new product</h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <form method="post" action="manageProduct.php">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="name" class="form-label">Product Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="price" class="form-label">Sale Price</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="price" min="0.01" step=".01" name="price"
                               required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="addProduct" value="Add Product">Add Product</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

manageProduct.php:

```
    if (isset($_POST['addProduct'])) {
        try {
            $sql = "insert into sells (name, username, price) 
                            values (:name, :username, :price)";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':name' => $_POST['name'],
                ':username' => $user,
                ':price' => $_POST['price']);
            $_SESSION['success'] = 'Product added successfully!';
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'Failed to add your product!';
        }
}
```

my bootstrap version:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"
        integrity="sha256-JlqSTELeR4TLqP0OG9dxM7yDPqX1ox/HfgiSLBj8+kM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: _"I found that if a user already has products stored in the database, the modal will work as expected. However, if a user hasn't posted any product yet, click the button will not open the modal but cause this error"_ - then I guess something about the HTML you are generating must be different, based on whether the user has already added products before, or not ... Have you _implemented_ anything in that regard? If not, can you spot any relevant differences, when you compare the generated HTML code in both cases?

Comment: Your HTML works fine! It must be some other reason.

Comment: The only difference is if no product stored, the table will be empty, (only column names).

Comment: Problems like this almost never involve both back-end code (PHP) and front-end code (Bootstrap) since they don't communicate. Please reduce the problem description to just one venue and update tags accordingly.

Comment: Because I actually not sure where the problem locates and I would like to give specific description about my situation. So if I need to delete some part, which part do you think I need to delete? Frontend or back end?

Comment: most likely, you're missing the modal html in that case..

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the unique modal's id dynamically for every time when modal is created.

Step 1: update it in ***data-bs-target***.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#UniqueModalId">
Add a new product
```

Step 2: update it in ***id*** attribute.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="UniqueModalId" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1"
     aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
....
</div>
```